# Rails subtract result for the previous result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, operators, slim-lang

Thanks at all for previous answers in my questions
I have more one trouble to show my results i need to show the weight of my patients in view day after day
and i need to show more one column "weight losted" this is the weight of the day - weight of the previous day  but here is my code

```
  p


table
thead
  tr
    th Date
    th Weight
    th IMC:
    th weight Losted:
p
strong pesos:
tbody
  - @patient.weight.each do |m|
    tr
      td  = m.date
      td  = m.weight
      td  = (m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f).round(2)
      td  = m.weight - ?????????



br
```

I have no idea how to make this, because is to many results and i dont know how i call the last result to subract of the actual result
help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [each_with_index()](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index)

```
- patient_weights = @patient.weight
- patient_weights.each_with_index do |m, i|
  tr
    td  = m.date
    td  = m.weight
    td  = (m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f).round(2)
    td  = (i > 0) ? (m.weight - patient_weights[i-1].weight) : "-"
```

Comment: NameError in Patients#weight
Showing /vagrant/projects/clinica2/app/views/patients/weight.html.slim where line #63 raised:

undefined local variable or method `i' for #<#<Class:0xa41346c>:0xb0f4dac>
Extracted source (around line #63):
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
          
             - else
                 td  = 'sem dados para este calculo'
             - if m.weight != nil
                 td  = (i > 0) ? (m.weight - patient_weights[i-1]) : "-"
             - else
                 td  = 'Sem peso para esse calculo'
   

Rails.root: /vagrant/projects/clinica2

Comment: Did you change the `each` to `.each_with_index do |m, i|`?

Comment: TypeError in Patients#weight
Showing /vagrant/projects/clinica2/app/views/patients/weight.html.slim where line #65 raised:

Weight can't be coerced into Float
Extracted source (around line #65):
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
          
                 td  = 'sem dados para este calculo'
   
             - if m.weight != nil
                 td  = (i > 0) ? (m.weight - patient_weights[i-1]) : "-"
             - else
                 td  = 'Sem peso para esse calculo'
   

Rails.root: /vagrant/projects/clinica2

Comment: What is the datatype of weight?

Comment: Corrected the answer. Had forgotten to get `weight` value from object. Sorry.